# Ember JS - Passing data between components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using Ember JS 2.12.0

I have created a component that runs an action on click and receives some data. I now need to pass this data into another component. How would I go about this? The docs do not seem to cover it.

Here is my component template:

```
<div class="play-button" {{action "playTrack" track}}> 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

And the component JS:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    actions: {
        playTrack(track){
            console.log(track);
        }
    }

});
```

How can I pass the track object into another component?

Comment: Refer this https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand your question you are asking about communication between distant components, that is there is not a parent-child relationship between the components to pass data in between. If there is a parent-child relation, you can use the traditionally approach of "Data down action up".

The best way to communicate between distant components is to use a `service`. Even a `service` can serve as a cross-cutting concern through the application; such as a session service. I would highly suggest to look at the [following](https://emberigniter.com/communication-between-distant-components/) article for a description regarding your case. It basically suggests making use of `service` as I already pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, after some more research I believe a service is the correct way to go about this.